# ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs in SpectralCoclustering in Python3.X

Tags: python-3.x, cluster-analysis, valueerror

```
data = np.genfromtxt("breastCancer.txt", delimiter=',').astype(np.float32)
data = data[~np.isnan(data).any(axis=1)]

ROW, COLUMN = data.shape

label = data[:, -1]
input = data[:, 1:COLUMN - 1]

scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1.0, 1.0))
scaler.fit(input)
input = scaler.transform(input)

model = SpectralCoClustering(n_clusters=3, random_state=0)
model.fit(input)
```

I tried to get biclustering of dataset that is in a range of (-1.0, 1.0). In my data I don't have any inf or nan. But it throws an error of `ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs in SpectralCoclustering`. Can you please help me? I need a dataset in a range (-1, 1) so I dont want to change it in a positive range.

Comment: I tried for a dataset in a range of [0,1]. It throws same error too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent two days figuring out the same problem. My solution: before doing `model.fit(input)` I removed columns with only zeros from `input`:

```
remaining_collumns=input.getnnz(1)>0
input=input[remaining_collumns,:]
model.fit(input)
```

Also note, that in my case `input` is returned by `TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform` and was in form of `sparse.csr.csr_matrix`

Comment: Hi!! Just wanted to let you know that you helped a data science student (aka, me) finish his program today! Thank you so much!!